# Yasnippets: How to add if statements that check for regex?

Tags: latex, yasnippet

I would like to replicate some of the snippets shown in
[this blog post](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/)

Some of the snippets shown in that post involved if statements that check for regexp in snippet fields as well as checking for regex before a snippet

Can yasnippets do the same? If yes, then how?

I did not see anything like that in the documentaion

Answer (score 2):

Yasnippets can execute arbitrary lisp code [writing it inside back quotes](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#orgcde188c)

In your case you can write something like

```
`(if (re-search-forward "regex" nil t)
     "some text"
   "another one")`
```